# Keep chrome extensions icons permanently ordered

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I like to have the extensions like Gmail Checker and Google Voice checker closest to my eyes, therefore closer to the url bar. I have tried disabling and enabling extensions to order them correctly, but once I close chrome, they appear in a different order (always the same undesirable "different" order).  Is there a way to prevent them from rearranging themselves? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Unfortunately, as of now, there seem to be [no](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5a1bf0026bd6283a&hl=en) [way](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6b989b0d81ecd7a8&hl=en#all) to [make](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=56377224915c3a38&hl=en#all) Chrome remember the order of extension icons.</del>

Chrome 5.0.322.2 dev edition allows you to reorder the Extensions by dragging.

Comment: huh...I wonder when it'll happen..

Comment: Pitch in a comment, more comments means more people asking means more likely they're going to add it :) 
Else if you you a bit of programming, you could probably try your hand at it :)

Comment: i know python and c++, no java...

Comment: IIRC Chromium uses C++

Comment: I have 10.0.648.134 on Windows 7 64, and I can drag the extensions to reorder, but they get rearranged when I restart chrome.

Comment: @BenCollins - I cannot reproduce that. I'm on dev ( 11.0.696.12 ) and the extension order is retained

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doesn't seem like dragging the extension icons worked till 5.0.366.0 dev.

I had 5.0.360.0 with which I couldn't drag and drop the icons, hence I ended up here. However, as I went to `Chrome` > `About` to double check which developer version I had, Chrome had automatically installed 5.0.366.0. So after a restart, dragging the extension icons now worked... lol